# Qmessagebox background and text color

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qmessagebox

[image]

I have message response as you see on the above. I've managed to colour background to black:

```
msg.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
```

I've tried with same way for the text but it looks like this:

[image]

```
msg.setStyleSheet("text-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
```

***My only purpose is texts are white and background is black...***

Here is my part of code:

```
msg = QMessageBox()
msg.setText("Message has been sended")
msg.setWindowTitle("SENT")
msg.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("black tic.png"))
msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
msg.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);")
msg.setStyleSheet("text-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
msg.exec_()
```

Comment: `msg.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255)")`.

Answer (score 3):

To change the color of the text of a `QMessageBox`, you have to use the following line

```py
msgBox.setStyleSheet("QLabel{ color: white}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it works fine...

```
msg.setStyleSheet("color:white;background:black")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
msg = QMessageBox()
msg.setText("Message has been sended")
msg.setWindowTitle("SENT")
msg.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("black tic.png"))
msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
msg.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
msg.exec_()
```